# $x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can we cause this relation to be true?

> $$x \sin\theta + y \cos\theta = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2  } \tag{$\star$}$$

I know the identity

$$x \sin\theta + y \cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\; \sin\left(\theta + \operatorname{atan}\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
What can make the sine part "$1$" (or just approximately "$1$") so that $(\star)$ holds?

Comment: That proof is impossible.

Comment: @Hetebrij why so ?

Comment: $x=7$ $y=5$ and $\theta = 3 \pi$.

Comment: If you put $x=3$, $y=1$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ then the identity is wrong.

Comment: do you want to find the set of variables where the equality holds?

Comment: Ideally the identity is $x sin\theta + y cos\theta = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2} sin(\theta + tan^-1 (y/x))$ but what can make the sine part approximately equal to 1 so that this is possible??

Comment: It asks for the proof of an obviously wrong statement.

Comment: @ghujari What is $\theta$? The result is true if $\tan\theta=\frac{x}{y}$. But in the usual Cartesian setup we have $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @ghujari: I edited your question to better match what you seem to be saying in your comment. Please check whether it means what you intend.

Comment: What if $0\leqslant x \geqslant1$ and $0\leqslant y \geqslant1$ ?

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates.  $ r \cos \theta \sin \theta + r \sin \theta \cos \theta = r ; \,sin  2 \theta =1 ;\, \theta = \pi/4, \pi/4 +n \, \pi.. $

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should've tried this out yourself and should give your details about your effort made.
Anyway it is not an identity. Here's workout:-

set:

$$ x=r \cos(\alpha)~~ \text{and}~~ y=r \sin(\alpha)$$

Substituting back in he equation we get

$$ r \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + r \sin(\alpha) \cos(\theta)=r$$

$$ \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + \sin(\alpha) \cos(\theta)=1$$

$$ \sin(\alpha + \theta) = 1$$

$$ \alpha + \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n \pi/2 ~~~~\text{   - (*)}$$

Last equation gives relation between $\theta$ and $\alpha$, but both are arbitrary variables.

Therefore by contradiction the equation $x \sin\theta + y \cos\theta  = \sqrt { x^2 + y^2  }$ is not an identity.

Answer (score 1):

The equality holds if $$(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)=\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This identity is not correct. Take for example $x=2,\,y=3,\,\theta=0^\circ.$
Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{4+9}=3.605\neq 3=x\sin \theta + y \cos \theta.$

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I will suppose that either $\theta$ is fixed and solve the equation for $(x,y)$ or that $x$ and/or $y$ are fixed and solve for $\theta$. But first, 
let us write $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and consider the angle $\alpha$ such that
$x=r\sin\alpha$ and $y=r\cos\alpha$. This is always possible. (Use for instance $\alpha=2\operatorname{arctan}\frac{x}{y+r}$.) The equation becomes
$$r\sin\theta\sin\alpha+r\cos\theta\cos\alpha=r\cos(\theta-\alpha)=r.\tag 1$$

- Case 1 : $\theta$ is given.

This equation (1) is verified as soon as $\alpha=\theta+k\,2\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. The choice of $r$ is arbitrary. The solutions's ensemble is  therefore
$$\left\{(r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta)\mid\,r\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$

- Case 2 : $x$ and $y$ are given.
  Then $r$ and $\alpha$ are also given and the solutions of equation (1) are the angles $\theta$ such that $\cos(\theta-\alpha)=1$. The ensemble of solutions is 
  $$\alpha+2\pi\mathbb Z=\{\alpha+k2\pi\,\mid\,k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$
- Case 3 : $x$ is given. 
  In this case, we have much more latitude. If $x=0$ the ensemble of solutions $(y,\theta)$ is
  $$\{(y,\theta) \mid \cos\theta=\operatorname{sgn}(y) \}=\mathbb{R}^+\times2\pi\mathbb Z\cup \mathbb{R}^-\times\left(\pi+2\pi\mathbb Z\right).$$
  If $x\neq 0$ the ensemble of solutions is 
  $$\left\{\left(y,2\operatorname{arctan}\frac{x}{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+k2\pi\right)\,\Bigg|\, y\in\mathbb R,\,k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$
  The case where $y$ is given is obtained by swapping $x$ and $y$ in this case.